# Visual Studio 2010 Crashes when Creating or Editing a Report (.rdlc) with the Report Designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, report-designer, crash

This is an issue I had with VS 2010 RC and was hoping would be solved with the first official release. Sadly it wasn't.

What I have is a number of reports originally created with VS 2008. When opening any of these for editing in VS 2010's Report Designer VS hangs for about two minutes and then shuts down. Same happens when creating a new report using the wizard. Only difference is that a dialog opens up showing a "Loading ..." message then hangs for about the same amount of time and crashes.

Running devenv /log gives nothing of value.

The Windows Application Event Viewer shows only this:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe,
>   version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp:
>   0x4ba1fab3 Faulting module name:
>   clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time
>   stamp: 0x4ba1d9ef Exception code:
>   0xc00000fd Fault offset: 0x00001919
>   Faulting process id: 0xc38 Faulting

And this:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4927 -
>   Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (6F551CF2) (0)

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

**OR -- Is there a better tool for rapidly creating decent reports within a WinForms app?**

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Today i had the same problem, i came up with a workaround:
open the .sln file first with your visual studio, than change to windows explorer and open the .rdlc file from there, it should pop up at your visual studio as a seperate tab.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man that's some crash. And I'm doing reports in 2008, moving to 2010 soon. I can't help you on the error, and after looking for a report designer for days now, I found two: [MS Report builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6&displaylang=en) and [Pebble](http://pebblereports.com/). The second you need to pay for. Both of those save to rdl though, the server version of the report format.

I then went on a fruitless mission [converting rdl to rdlc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(VS.80).aspx) (client-side reports), not as quick and easy as they make it seem.

And I heard so much about SSRS, I really don't want to give my hopes up. I wish I have a better answer for you. I'm still looking and will post back if any *working* report designers blink into existence.